# dblclick() method in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ondblclick

I am writing a jQuery dblclick() method. I am trying to show a hidden menu when double clicked on a button. I am creating a button named "Menu" in my html file with href attribute.

The href attribute in HTML file is this:

```
<a href="#" id="menu_link">Menu</a>
        <div id="menu" style="display: none;">
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</a><br/>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a><br/>
          <a href="https://www.apple.com/">Apple</a>
              
        </div>
```

So, when "Menu" is double clicked it show three options - youtube,facebook,apple

and then in js file, I am creating a dblclick() function and giving them id "menu_link" and then using show() to display the hidden menu.

This is what I have in js file:

```
$('#menu_link').dblclick(function(){
      $('#menu').show();
    });
```

It doesn't work. When I doubleclick the "menu" option it doesn't show me anything.

In Html file :

```
<a href="#" id="menu_link">Menu</a>
        <div id="menu" style="display: none;">
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</a><br/>
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a><br/>
          <a href="https://www.apple.com/">Apple</a>
              
        </div>
```

In js file :

```
$(function() {
$('#menu_link').dblclick(function(){
      $('#menu').show();
    });
  });
```

The link to the project - https://glitch.com/edit/#!/comp484-proj2-km

Comment: Yes, the link for the project is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors. Fix it. It prevents this line from ever being reached. The error is not in the code you’ve shown here. You use `pet_info.weight` before ever defining `pet_info`. Try using your browser’s [debug capabilities](//ali-dev.medium.com/how-to-easily-debug-in-javascript-5bac70f94f1a). See [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](/q/25385173/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

I just inspected your project and found 2 problems.

1. You'll need to fix **checkAndUpdatePetInfoInHtml();**
   According to my inspections, this function is causing some problems and not letting the program finish. Therefore the double-click check won't be called.
2. In the A tag, the href is just refreshing the page. Removing the menu. Just remove the href.

**Before**

```
<a href="#" id="menu_link">Menu</a>
```

**After**

```
<a id="menu_link">Menu</a>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: No, `href="#"` will not refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try like this:

add in js-File:

```
function openMenu(){
    $("#menu").css("display", "block");
  }
```

change your div id=menu to:

```
<a id="menu_link" ondblclick='openMenu()'>Menu</a>
    <div id="menu" style="display: none;">
              <a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</a><br/>
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a><br/>
              <a href="https://www.apple.com/">Apple</a>
                  
            </div>
```

I've tried it at glitch and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

change css display to block

```
$('#menu_link').dblclick(function(){
      $('#menu').css("display", "block");
    });
  })
```

Comment: That’s exactly what [`.show`](//api.jquery.com/show) does.